# Parts of an object are disappearing in Object Mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, object-mode

I am working on a 3 storey building and I needed to move the columns a meter to the right. I used edit mode to move the faces and everything was smooth, but when I switched back to Object mode all the columns and parts of the roof/floor disappear. It's completely fine in edit mode but messed up in object mode and I really don't know what causes that. Thanks in advance

[image: Building in edit mode, everything is good]

[image: Building in object mode, really messed up]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it doesn't look like a Clipping problem, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I added the blend file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are booleaning your object with a big cube called *Cube.002*, disable this *Boolean* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Oooh I totally forgot about that, my bad. Thank you!